# libvirt error when enabling hugepages for guest

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to set up a VM using libvirt and KVM through virt-manager (and virsh command line) with hugepages support and I get an error when enabling the option in the domain XML. Don't know where the problem is.

I am using the following packages (utopic repository):

- libvirt-bin 1.2.8-0ubuntu11
- qemu-kvm 2.1+dfsg-4ubuntu6

I have configured hugepages following this [guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages). Here is some info about current configuration:

```
chaicko@gauss:~$ cat /proc/mounts | grep huge
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,mode=1770,gid=126 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb 0 0

chaicko@gauss:~$ hugeadm --explain
Total System Memory: 15808 MB

Mount Point          Options
/dev/hugepages       rw,relatime,mode=1770,gid=126

Huge page pools:
      Size  Minimum  Current  Maximum  Default
   2097152     2176     2176     2176        *

Huge page sizes with configured pools:
2097152

chaicko@gauss:~$ getent group kvm
kvm:x:126:chaicko
```

This is the domain XML:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>win8</name>
  <uuid>b85bbb9a-745f-4293-a990-1e1726240ef0</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <memoryBacking>
    <hugepages/>
  </memoryBacking>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-utopic'>hvm</type>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Haswell</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
      <source dev='/dev/vmvg/win8'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/chaicko/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1-81.iso'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/chaicko/Downloads/WINDOWS_8.1_Pro_X64/Windows_8.1_Pro_X64_Games4theworld.org.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:48:ca:09'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0b' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-drive'/>
    <qemu:arg value='if=pflash,readonly,format=raw,file=/usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

If I remove the `<memoryBacking>` option then it works but if not it fails with the the following error:

```
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor:
```

Also I have uncommented the following line in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

```
hugetlbfs_mount = "/dev/hugepages"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, in order to use hugepages with `libvirt` in *Ubuntu*, you just have to set `KVM_HUGEPAGES=1` in the file `/etc/default/qemu-kvm` and restart.

This is related with this [bugfix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1250216).